# What does this javascript function do?

Tags: javascript

```
var n = {
        Android: /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent),
        Safari: /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent) && !/CriOS|Chrome|Mercury/.test(navigator.userAgent)
    };
```

I am curious about the /Android/i.test() function. If this a function in another file? I'm guessing it is not since the next function /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test() is even more curious. Is it a string compare on the 'Android' string? Could anyone provide me with some documentation?

Comment: I think it's to check if you're browsing on Safari or on Android.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test

Comment: *I know what a regular expression is but this synthax was completely unknown to me.* Which syntax? The `/Android/` syntax for a regular expression, or the `obj.method()` syntax to call a method? `/Android/i.test()` is just the two syntaxes sitting side by side.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a method call on the regular expression `/Android/i`.

The `/Android/i` part represents a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) or "regex", which is used to do pattern-matching on strings.

A regular expression has a method called `test`, and returns `true` if it matches. You could rewrite that hunk above as:

```
androidRegex = /Android/i;
safariRegex = /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i;
criOsregex = /CriOS|Chrome|Mercury/;
var n = {
    Android: androidRegex.test(navigator.userAgent),
    Safari: safariRegex.test(navigator.userAgent) && !criOsregex.test(navigator.userAgent)
};
```

The syntax for declaring a regular expression in Javascript is `/pattern/flags`, where `pattern` is the pattern to compare against, and `flags` are additional options.

The Android one is very simple: it just compares against the string `Android`, with the flag `i` to make it case-insensitive.

The Safari one is slightly more complex, because it uses "alternation" to match `iPhone`, `iPad`, or `iPod`. The `|` character delimits alternates in a regex.

The CriOS regex, notably, leaves off the `i` flag because the author wants it to be case-sensitive (the default).

Comment: I know what a regular expression is but this synthax was completely unknown to me. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @OzanKurt I read somewhere that top StackOverflow-scorers frequently jump in on a question with a 1-line answer then expand it afterwards, having staked the top spot. It... seems to work ;)

Comment: @N3dst4 I have been using that lately too. ;) Nice to see some people earning rep. :)

Comment: @N3dst4 fastest gun in the west :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `var n` is declared as an object with `two properties` which are called `Android` and `Safari`.

When the object is `initialized`, both properties are executed returning a `boolean` result either the `User Agent` of the `Navigator` is **Android** for the first one, or **iPhone**, **iPad** or **iPod** for the second one.

Therefore, you can expect both `properties` to be either `true` or `false`.

**EDIT**: As @N3dst4 stated, this is called regular expression. See his reply for more info about it.